# Yii how to redirect to particular URL

Tags: yii, url-rewriting

I have used url beautifier to remove index.php?r= from URL. it works fine.

now i want user to redirect to URL if user hits particular url.

suppose

```
http://localhost/xm/xmds.php?wsdl

To

http://localhost/xm_demo_menu/WebService/service
```

how to achieve this. i search lot on google but not found material relevant to my problem

any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you talking about Redirect OR Rewriting ??

Comment: problem solved thanks.... @SanjayMohnani i was talking about redirecting.... bt problem solved by rewriting

Comment: Yes .. I feel that you need rewriting for this. I hope you done through configuration rewriting options. Is it ??

Answer (score 0):

I do not see where the problem should be. See [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail)
In you controller, simply call:

```
$this->redirect("http://localhost/xm_demo_menu/WebService/service");
```